# Did MacGyver really use a vacuum to climb a building?

Tags: macgyver

This is the new MacGyver Season 2 Episode 3.  It appears he climbs the side of the building with a vacuum.  Is this really what they meant?

[image]

I guess my question is this a suction cup mechanism or really a vacuum?

Comment: 1) I'm a little unclear on what you're asking here.  He climbs a building using a vaccum and you want to know if what they said is really what they meant?  Or do you mean "could this really be done?"  2) You appear to have linked to an image that *looks like* a video clip, but isn't, actually.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes I'm trying to figure out if I missing something in the story line.  Yes they don't have any close ups that I could find of the scene which is why I am confused.  It is paused sorry for the play button(I don't think I could link to actual video considering I don't believe it isn't available for free online).  I guess my question is this a suction cup mechanism or really a vacuum.

Comment: @William Does the show _say_ it's a vacuum?

Comment: @JMac no but it appears to be on a janitor/cleaning cart so I'm assuming it is.  I'm assuming there are scripts somewhere that would clarify this.

Comment: On "Duck quacks don't echo", Lee Mack and Paul Hollywood climbed a wall using a vacuum contraption. (Not suction cups.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this image, it looks like 2 vacuum cleaners attached to some sort of plate/suction cup to create the seal to the windows.

[Giphy](https://www.facebook.com/MacGyverCBS/videos/1727816770857301/)

[image: MacGyver scaling building]

Comment: How do you operate something like this I wonder...

Comment: [Mythbusters](http://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/mythbusters-the-search/mythbusters-the-search-myth-database/myth-database-climbing-like-spider-man/)